# android Bitmap getPixel

Tags: android, colors, bitmap, getpixel

I need to get the color of a pixel in order to compare it with a color from my color.xml file, but all values are negative and this comparison will always return a false result. How to get the proper color value? This color may be transparent. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501527/get-rgbvalues-of-bitmap-in-android) but I need an answer, not a link to theory.

`bmp.getPixel(n.x, n.y)` is returning zero when I'm expecting to return a propper value for color `#00FFFFFF`

Thanks

Comment: Haven't done this in android but isn't something like Color c = bmp.getPixel(..., ...); available? => c.R, c.G, c.B. would be the rgb values.

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like this:

```
int pixel = Color.RED; //bmp.getPixel(n.x, n.y);
int a = Color.alpha(pixel);
int r = Color.red(pixel);
int g = Color.green(pixel);
int b = Color.blue(pixel);

String color = String.format("#%02X%02X%02X%02X", a, r, g, b); //#FFFF0000 for RED color
```

but instead of `Color.RED` you can put your `bmp.getPixel(...)` method.

Hope that helps

Best Regards